# How do I rebuild/make .iml files in maven multi-module project in Intellij 13.1.4

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, pom.xml

I'm working in a multi-module maven project in Intellij.  There was a snapshot update in another module which required an update in a few POMs.  Normally I will click the "Re-import all maven projects" from the maven plugins tool then do a full build.

However, this time the .iml files associated with the changed POMs weren't being updated.  It wasn't until I did "Build->Rebuild Project" that the .iml files were updated.  Does anyone know how to update .iml files as part of a build configuration?

Note:  Before rebuilding the project, I know mvn at least picked up on the change because my local .m2 repo had the latest snapshot.

EDIT #1: So, this is also true if I add a maven runtime dependency in a module.  It won't pick up the change unless I do rebuild project.

Comment: The .iml file will update when IntelliJ is ready to update it. You shouldn't be concerned with it. You shouldn't have .iml files checked into your version control system (svn, git), btw.

Comment: But the iml file was out of sync with the POM and i was being forced to use the incorrect (out of date) snapshot which meant my code wasn't compiling.  And yes, i dont check in my .iml files

Comment: That sounds unlikely -- I've used IntelliJ since it was first released, in many different situations, on different machines, and operating systems, and I've never had a problem like that. Perhaps something else is wrong? What does the dependency for the out of date snapshot look like? What repository are you using (nexus, artifactory, etc.)?

Comment: We use Artifactory.  I'm sorry, I dont quite know what you're looking for with "what ... dependency ... look like"  Yeah, def somethign else could be wrong, i'm not sure what though :-/.  Pressing rebuild project did update the .iml though.

Comment: I'm not knowledgable about maven, but my colleague said it was just a normal jar dependency

Comment: Do you have common parent pom for the modules or every module has independant pom?

Comment: You can always tell IntelliJ to explicitly reimport Maven configuration.  Use the "two arrows in a circle" icon to the top left in the Maven pane.

Comment: Perhaps the merge caused the .iml files to become invalid.

Comment: I had a similar problem with the iml-file. It occured, when local dependencies (to a local classes folder) was added by an other developer, which were missing in my project. intellij seems to have trouble changing the iml in this situations.

Answer (score 4):

I've experienced similar issues with newer versions of IntelliJ (2018.2.7) where my .iml is out of date. It happens inconsistently, so I'm not sure what the root cause is, but the following work around allows me to avoid doing a full rebuild:

1. Delete the .iml file and .idea folder for the project
2. Reimport the pom.xml for the project
3. IntelliJ will automagically regenerate an updated .iml file.

Answer (score 4):

Had the same issue and in addition to deleting the .iml file as in the previous answer, delete the .idea folder as well and restart the IDE or import the project by pom file.

new .iml file is created with all maven dependencies